# Single cell sum and blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I'm using this macro to sum individual numbers, separated by comma, in single cell

```
Function Individual(R As Range) As Double
   Individual = Evaluate(Replace(R.Value, ",", "+"))
End Function
```

Function looks like this =Individual(XY), where XY is "source" cell where individual numbers are written.

How to modify macro to write 0 to "target" cell when "source" cell is blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Individual(R As Range) As Double
  if len(r.value) > 0 then
    Individual = Evaluate(Replace(R.Value, ",", "+"))
  else
    Individual = 0
  end if
End Function
```

Comment: Tnx FreeMan, you saved my day :)

Comment: Glad to help, @Marko . Mark that as the solution (click the check mark) - makes it easier for others to know it worked when they come across it in a search.